# Python scraping 'things to do' from tripadvisor

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, tripadvisor

From [this](https://www.tripadvisor.com/Attractions-g34438-Activities-Miami_Florida.html) page, I want to scrape the list 'Types of Things to Do in Miami' (you can find it near the end of the page). Here's what I have so far:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# Define header to prevent errors
user_agent = "Mozilla/44.0.2 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/48.0.2564.109 Safari/9.0.2"

headers = {'User-Agent': user_agent}

new_url = "https://www.tripadvisor.com/Attractions-g34438-Activities-Miami_Florida.html"
# Get response from url
response = requests.get(new_url, headers = headers)
# Encode response for parsing
html = response.text.encode('utf-8')
# Soupify response
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml")

tag_elements = soup.findAll("a", {"class":"attractions-attraction-overview-main-Pill__pill--23S2Q"})

# Iterate over tag_elements and exctract strings
tags_list = []
for i in tag_elements:
    tags_list.append(i.string)
```

The problem is, I get values like `'Good for Couples (201)', 'Good for Big Groups (130)', 'Good for Kids (100)'` which are from the 'Commonly Searched For in Miami' area of the page which is below the "Types of Things..." part of the page. I also don't get some of the values that I need like `"Traveler Resources (7)", "Day Trips (7)"` etc. The class names for both these lists "Things to do..." and "Commonly searched..." are same and I'm using class in `soup.findAll()` which might be the cause of this problem I guess. What is the correct way to do this? Is there some other approach that I should take?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get only the contents within ***`Types of Things to Do in Miami`*** headers is a little bit tricky. To do so you need to define the selectors in an organized manner like I did below. The following script should click on the `See all` buton under the aforesaid headers. Once the click is initiated, the script will parse the relevant content you look for:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support import ui
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
wait = ui.WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
driver.get("https://www.tripadvisor.com/Attractions-g34438-Activities-Miami_Florida.html")

show_more = wait.until(lambda driver: driver.find_element_by_css_selector("[class='ui_container'] div:nth-of-type(1) .caret-down"))
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();",show_more)
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source,"lxml")
items = [item.text for item in soup.select("[class='ui_container'] div:nth-of-type(1) a[href^='/Attractions-']")]
print(items)   
driver.quit()
```

The output It produces:

```
['Tours (277)', 'Outdoor Activities (255)', 'Boat Tours & Water Sports (184)', 'Shopping (126)', 'Nightlife (126)', 'Spas & Wellness (109)', 'Fun & Games (67)', 'Transportation (66)', 'Museums (61)', 'Sights & Landmarks (54)', 'Nature & Parks (54)', 'Food & Drink (27)', 'Concerts & Shows (25)', 'Classes & Workshops (22)', 'Zoos & Aquariums (7)', 'Traveler Resources (7)', 'Day Trips (7)', 'Water & Amusement Parks (5)', 'Casinos & Gambling (3)', 'Events (2)']
```

Answer (score 3):

This is pretty straightforward to do in the browser:

```
filters = driver.execute_script("return [...document.querySelectorAll('.filterName a')].map(a => a.innerText)")
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to be able to click the show more to see all the available. So use something like selenium. This includes waits to ensure all elements are present and for drop down to be clickable.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

d = webdriver.Chrome()
d.get("https://www.tripadvisor.com/Attractions-g34438-Activities-Miami_Florida.html")
WebDriverWait(d,5).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,".filter_list_0 div a")))
WebDriverWait(d, 5).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#taplc_attraction_filters_clarity_0 span.ui_icon.caret-down"))).click()
tag_elements = WebDriverWait(d,5).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".filter_list_0 div a")))
tags_list = [i.text for i in tag_elements]
print(tags_list)
d.quit()
```

---

[image]

---

Without selenium I only get 15 items

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

user_agent = "Mozilla/44.0.2 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/48.0.2564.109 Safari/9.0.2"
headers = {'User-Agent': user_agent}
new_url = "https://www.tripadvisor.com/Attractions-g34438-Activities-Miami_Florida.html"
response = requests.get(new_url, headers = headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "lxml")
tag_elements = soup.select('#component_3 > div > div > div:nth-of-type(12) > div:nth-of-type(1) > div > div a')

tags_list = [i.text for i in tag_elements]       
print(tags_list)
```

Comment: The line `WebDriverWait(d,5).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,".filter_list_0 div a")))` results in a `TimeoutException: Message:` with no message displayed. I changed the time to 10 and 20 but it results in the same.

Comment: Odd. What happens if you comment out that line and increase the wait on the next line to 10? You can always execute_script on the dropdown otherwise to move things along.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you'll need to use selenium. The problem is the dropdown doesn't show the remaining options until after you click it.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

options = Options()
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
driver.get('https://www.tripadvisor.com/Attractions-g34438-Activities-Miami_Florida.html')

WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="component_3"]/div/div/div[12]/div[1]/div/div/div/div[1]/span')))


driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="component_3"]/div/div/div[12]/div[1]/div/div/div/div[1]/span'))
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="component_3"]/div/div/div[12]/div[1]/div/div/div/div[1]/span'))


html = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')

items = soup.findAll('a', {'class':'attractions-attraction-overview-main-Pill__pill--23S2Q'})
#You could use this to not just get text but also the ['href'] too. 

for item in items:
    print(item.get_text())


driver.quit()
```